# How a profinite group can be obtained from its normal open subgroups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $\Delta$ be a set, each element of which is a profinite group (2 distinct elements of $\Delta$ may be isomorphic). Under what conditions on $\Delta$, there exists a profinite group $G$ which has $\Delta$ as the family of its normal open subgroups? By that I mean, there is a bijection $u$ from $\Delta$ onto the set of normal open subgroups of $G$, such that $H$ is topologically isomorphic to $u(H)$ for every $H\in\Delta$?

Comment: Certainly they need to form a directed system, in the sense that, for each $N, N' \in \Delta$, there is $N'' \in \Delta$ that injects into both with normal, cofinite index.  Do you mean $\Delta$ to consist of the *proper* normal open subgroups?  Otherwise it seems possible that directed + has a (unique) maximal element is enough.

Comment: I think OP means that the data is the a set $\Delta$ of isomorphism classes of profinite groups, and the question is whether there exists a profinite groups whose set of isomorphism classes of open normal subgroups is exactly $\Delta$. (In this case, the answer is plainly: if and only if there is some $G\in\Delta$ such that every $H\in\Delta$ is isomorphic to some open normal subgroup of $G$, and such that every open normal subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to some element of $\Delta$.)

Comment: @YCor Thanks for your useful comment. But really I want $\Delta$ to be all of my open normal subgroups, not only the isomorphism classes.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly $\Delta$ is a set of profinite groups, and you're asking whether there is an isomorphism-preserving bijection from $\Delta$ to the set of normal open subgroups of some profinite group.

Comment: @YCor Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Do you have some motivation? It's hard to imagine an answer that is not a tautological restatement of the condition. Also as regards the connection with the title, necessarily $G$ should be isomorphic to some element of $\Delta$. So $G$ is not really obtained from the collection of normal subgroups, it just appears among them.